# Extract and modify text from JSON (Apache Ni-Fi)

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm using InvokeHttp to get json as response from REST API.
My json looks like:

```
{
    "resourceNames": [
        "customers/123",
        "customers/12345",
        "customers/555",
        "customers/9890"
    ]
}
```

How can i extract from this json 4 strings without customers prefix?

```
123
12345
555
9890
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JoltTransformJSON -> PutDatabaseRecord using the following JOLT spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "resourceNames": {
        "*": {
          "customers/*": {
            "$(0,1)": "[].id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

That will create the following output:

```
[ {
  "id" : "123"
}, {
  "id" : "12345"
}, {
  "id" : "555"
}, {
  "id" : "9890"
} ]
```

which you can then send to PutDatabaseRecord and it will insert a row for each JSON object in your flow file (assuming you're using a JsonTreeReader in PutDatabaseRecord) with the given value into the `id` column.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if you want to use pure NiFi processors you would use a ReplaceText to clean the **"customers/"**
[image]

**Wil give you this :**

```
{
    "resourceNames": [
        "123",
        "12345",
        "555",
        "9890"
    ]
}
```

And you can use **EvaluateJson** to parse it with a `valX = $.resourceNames.[*]`

But if you want to promote this to a database insert, you would do a split on the incoming flow instead of putting it in a attribute.

You could use `splitjson` insdted of **EvaluateJson** - with split on `$.resourceNames` then ExtractText with an added attribute lets say `datapoint` = `(?s)(^.*$)` value which is then sent to PutSQL where you `SQL Statement` looks like `insert into mytbl values (${datapoint})`.

Again - you could use a `PutRecord` proc for a more performant setup , but that will require setting other stuff and is a bit more complex, if you have large numbers of flows maybe `PutRecord` is the route, the `Split, Evaluate, extract` processors endup beeing very slow and they consume alot of ram.

Is quite heavy - due to the nature of **ReplaceText**, and also if your string changes you can pass it as a parameter.

One good approach would be a **JoltTransformJSON** processor, is quite tricky to get the **Jolt Specification** right, but it will much faster than ReplaceText.

Comment: Thanks, i got json looks like: `["123","12345","555","9890"]`. How can I put this flowfile content to database as id column? Each value from json = new row in database.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way would be with `ExecuteScript` and a little Groovy script that would use Groovy's JsonSlurper to parse the JSON, extract the values and then rewrite the flowfile's content.

Comment: You love your Groovy stuff!

Comment: What can I say? I'm a developer.

Comment: same here - its just python is so limited when interactig with nifi

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with Groovy, if you already have the original JSON you can do something like this:

```
def output = input['resourceNames'].collect{ name ->
  name - 'customers/'
}
println JsonOutput.toJson(output)
```

This will produce the following output:

```
["123","12345","555","9890"]
```

And here is the full sample code that I created for this:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper
import groovy.json.JsonOutput

String json = '''{
    "resourceNames": [
        "customers/123",
        "customers/12345",
        "customers/555",
        "customers/9890"
    ]
}'''

Map input = new JsonSlurper().parseText(json)

def output = input['resourceNames'].collect{ name ->
  name - 'customers/'
}

println JsonOutput.toJson(output)
```